# Differnce between linux write and sendfile syscall

Tags: linux, sockets, sendfile

Im programming webserver (C), which should send big files. My question is:
What are the main differences in two syscalls: `write` and `sendfile`. Does `sendfile` depends on size of socket system buffer? I noticed that `write` often writes less then I requested.

For example, if got many requests for one file: should i open it, copy into memory and use `write`, or maybe I can do `sendfile` for each client?

Thanks in advance for all answers.

Answer (score 6):

Please read `sendfile`(2).

`sendfile()` copies data between one file descriptor and another.  Because this copying is done within the kernel, `sendfile()` is more efficient than the combination of `read`(2) and `write`(2), which would require transferring data to and from user space.

Regarding return value any of `write`/`read`/`senfile` calls do not guarantee that entire block of data is written/read/sent